# Proof of continued fraction identity of subfactorial

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, continued-fractions

This question is part of a wider conjecture I have formed with someone which has its roots in [Raayoni *et al.* (2019)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.00205.pdf). The subfactorial function can be written as $$!n=\frac{n!}e+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+2-\dfrac1{n+3-\dfrac2{n+4-\cdots}}}$$ which is equation [(17)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html) of the MathWorld documentation of subfactorial.

Is there a proof of this identity that can be found in the literature or elsewhere?

Comment: The OEIS says they heard about this formula from Peter Bala, so you could ask him.

Comment: It appears he has no contact details I can use.

Comment: Relevant paper https://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL17/Balof/balof22.pdf

Answer (score -2):

This is a particular case of a well know cfrac that can be found almost in any good textbook on continued fractions:
$$
{}_1F_1(1;c+1;z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^{k}}{(c+1)_k}\\
    =\cfrac{c}{c-z\,+}\,\cfrac{z}{c+1-z\,+}\,\cfrac{2z}{c+2-z\,+}\,\cfrac{3z}{c+3-z\,+}\,\ldots
$$
Just put $z=-1$, $c=n+1$.

If you don't like special functions then consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula . The formula above follows by direct application of Euler's formula.